# Synching PHP backed Admin portal with a Mobile app

Tags: php, android, web-services, mobile, synchronization

How is it possible to let the android application to know each and every change on admin portal by real time.

Our system is a school based application that works on our own tablets. In system there are Teachers, Parents, Students and a super admin. The tablet has daily attendance management, grades, exams, meetings and so many features for a school system, now the same user entities will have all the features mentioned in the Admin portal as well. lets say www.ourtabletapp.com/admin

so we have a need to synchronize every change that occurs in Admin portal to Android application in real time. (Then and there)

Currently we do have one way synchronization as in any changes to mobile app (new records, modify records and etc) eg: adding a new meeting, then updating it and so on. which is done using a REST API we have written, so mobile app will call the API each time to connect with our DB and synchronize.

**Question is what are the ways we have to make it two way synchronization? (Admin portal changes should reflect the mobile application immediately.)**

Update:
mobile app is located somewhere else in users mobiles. when a record is added or updated, how to send a request from Admin portal to mobile application and update the sql lite database in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the same logic that already has been implemented to notified the admin panel when someone update through the mobile app. let's say if anyone update the any student record from the admin panel , you have to update the DB first [ that already done i think ] and than you have to make the call of REST services that send the call to mobile app with the updated data.

let me know if you need any more help on this. you can share your structure for the better answer if needed.

Comment: When student record is updated in the Admin panel located in a website like www.myadminpanel.com/admin, the database is already updated. DB is also in the same server, but the question is how can we notify the mobile app as this particular record got updated from the admin portal immediately? mobile app is located somewhere else in users mobiles. how to send a request from Admin portal to mobile application and update the sql lite database in it?

Comment: @fireclaw48 - you can send the updated/deleted record ID with the rest services so mobile app can easily identity which record is updated.. I am not sure about the code so not much sure..but you can send [ARRAY [ STUDENT_ID => 10 ] ]